# Using not equal and nan together in python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have strange problem. I have the following code

```
if Group[NN1,8] != 'nan' :
    print("Group[NN1,8]",Group[NN1,8])
```

The value of Group[NN1,8] is nan,therefor i expect that print command not execute. But with my code it executes.
Result is

```
`('Group[NN1,8]', nan)`.
```

which doesn't have to print.  Is there any thing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're comparing a float with a string, which are never equal.

```
>>> float('nan')
nan

>>> 'nan'
'nan'

>>> float('nan') == 'nan'
False
```

In the special cases of `nan`, it doesn't even equal "itself":

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> x == x
False
```

You can use this instead:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.isnan(x)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

If using numpy, then you can also use:

```
np.invert(np.isnan(ds_cor_y))
```

it works like isnotnan(), so it will return TRUE if its a value and FALSE for nan.

Answer (score 1):

Not a number is unequal to any value, including nan.  You need to use `!math.isnan().`

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> x == x
False
>>> math.isnan(x)
True
```