# convert csv to specific json format

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file I want to convert it to json. I tried my best but I could not get it.
The csv is like this.

```
Income Statement,24/09/16,30/09/17,29/09/18,28/09/19,26/09/20,25/09/21,LTM
,,,,,,,
Revenues,,229234.00,265595.00,260174.00,274515.00,365817.00,378323.00
Total Revenues,,229234.00,265595.00,260174.00,274515.00,365817.00,378323.00
% Change YoY,,,15.9%,(2.0%),5.5%,33.3%,
Cost of Goods Sold,,"(141,048.00)","(163,756.00)","(161,782.00)","(169,559.00)","(212,981.00)","(215,572.00)"
Gross Profit,,88186.00,101839.00,98392.00,104956.00,152836.00,162751.00
% Change YoY,,,15.5%,(3.4%),6.7%,45.6%,
% Gross Margins,,38.5%,38.3%,37.8%,38.2%,41.8%,43.0%
Selling General & Admin Expenses,,"(15,261.00)","(16,705.00)","(18,245.00)","(19,916.00)","(21,973.00)","(22,791.00)"
R&D Expenses,,"(11,581.00)","(14,236.00)","(16,217.00)","(18,752.00)","(21,914.00)","(23,057.00)"
Other Operating Expenses,,"(26,842.00)","(30,941.00)","(34,462.00)","(38,668.00)","(43,887.00)","(45,848.00)"
Operating Income,,61344.00,70898.00,63930.00,66288.00,108949.00,116903.00
% Change YoY,,,15.6%,(9.8%),3.7%,64.4%,
```

What I want is a bit complicated

```
{"income_statement":
        {"24/9/16":
             {"Revenues(0)":"","Total Revenues(1)":"","   % Change YoY(2)":"","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"","Gross Profit(4)":"","   % Change YoY(5)":"","   % Gross Margins(6)":"","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"","R&D Expenses(8)":"","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"","Operating Income(10)":"","   % Change YoY(11)":"","   % Operating Margins(12)":"","Interest Expense(13)":"","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"","Income Tax Expense(19)":"","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"","Net Income to Company(21)":"","Net Income(22)":"","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"","   % Change YoY(28)":"","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"","   % Change YoY(30)":"","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"","   % Change YoY(32)":"","Dividends Per Share(33)":"","   % Change YoY(34)":"","Payout Ratio %(35)":"","Basic EPS(36)":"","EBITDA(37)":"","   % Change YoY(38)":"","EBITDAR(39)":"","R&D Expense(40)":"","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":""},
        "30/9/17":
             {"Revenues(0)":"229.234,00","Total Revenues(1)":"229.234,00","   % Change YoY(2)":"","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"(141.048,00)","Gross Profit(4)":"88.186,00","   % Change YoY(5)":"","   % Gross Margins(6)":"38,5 %","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"(15.261,00)","R&D Expenses(8)":"(11.581,00)","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"(26.842,00)","Operating Income(10)":"61.344,00","   % Change YoY(11)":"","   % Operating Margins(12)":"26,8 %","Interest Expense(13)":"(2323,00)","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"5201,00","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"(133,00)","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"64.089,00","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"64.089,00","Income Tax Expense(19)":"(15.738,00)","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"48.351,00","Net Income to Company(21)":"48.351,00","Net Income(22)":"48.351,00","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"48.351,00","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"21,1 %","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"48.351,00","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"21,1 %","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"2,30","   % Change YoY(28)":"","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"21.006,77","   % Change YoY(30)":"","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"20.868,97","   % Change YoY(32)":"","Dividends Per Share(33)":"0,60","   % Change YoY(34)":"","Payout Ratio %(35)":"26,4 %","Basic EPS(36)":"2,32","EBITDA(37)":"71.501,00","   % Change YoY(38)":"","EBITDAR(39)":"72.601,00","R&D Expense(40)":"11.581,00","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":"24,6 %"},
        "29/9/18":
             {"Revenues(0)":"265.595,00","Total Revenues(1)":"265.595,00","   % Change YoY(2)":"15,9 %","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"(163.756,00)","Gross Profit(4)":"101.839,00","   % Change YoY(5)":"15,5 %","   % Gross Margins(6)":"38,3 %","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"(16.705,00)","R&D Expenses(8)":"(14.236,00)","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"(30.941,00)","Operating Income(10)":"70.898,00","   % Change YoY(11)":"15,6 %","   % Operating Margins(12)":"26,7 %","Interest Expense(13)":"(3240,00)","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"5686,00","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"(441,00)","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"72.903,00","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"72.903,00","Income Tax Expense(19)":"(13.372,00)","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"59.531,00","Net Income to Company(21)":"59.531,00","Net Income(22)":"59.531,00","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"59.531,00","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"22,4 %","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"59.531,00","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"22,4 %","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"2,98","   % Change YoY(28)":"29,4 %","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"20.000,44","   % Change YoY(30)":"(4,8 %)","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"19.821,51","   % Change YoY(32)":"(5,0 %)","Dividends Per Share(33)":"0,68","   % Change YoY(34)":"13,3 %","Payout Ratio %(35)":"23,0 %","Basic EPS(36)":"3,00","EBITDA(37)":"81.801,00","   % Change YoY(38)":"14,4 %","EBITDAR(39)":"83.001,00","R&D Expense(40)":"14.236,00","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":"18,3 %"},
        "28/9/19":
             {"Revenues(0)":"260.174,00","Total Revenues(1)":"260.174,00","   % Change YoY(2)":"(2,0 %)","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"(161.782,00)","Gross Profit(4)":"98.392,00","   % Change YoY(5)":"(3,4 %)","   % Gross Margins(6)":"37,8 %","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"(18.245,00)","R&D Expenses(8)":"(16.217,00)","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"(34.462,00)","Operating Income(10)":"63.930,00","   % Change YoY(11)":"(9,8 %)","   % Operating Margins(12)":"24,6 %","Interest Expense(13)":"(3576,00)","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"4961,00","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"422,00","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"65.737,00","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"65.737,00","Income Tax Expense(19)":"(10.481,00)","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"55.256,00","Net Income to Company(21)":"55.256,00","Net Income(22)":"55.256,00","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"55.256,00","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"21,2 %","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"55.256,00","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"21,2 %","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"2,97","   % Change YoY(28)":"(0,3 %)","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"18.595,65","   % Change YoY(30)":"(7,0 %)","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"18.471,34","   % Change YoY(32)":"(6,8 %)","Dividends Per Share(33)":"0,75","   % Change YoY(34)":"10,3 %","Payout Ratio %(35)":"25,6 %","Basic EPS(36)":"2,99","EBITDA(37)":"76.477,00","   % Change YoY(38)":"(6,5 %)","EBITDAR(39)":"77.777,00","R&D Expense(40)":"16.217,00","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":"15,9 %"},
        "26/9/20":
             {"Revenues(0)":"274.515,00","Total Revenues(1)":"274.515,00","   % Change YoY(2)":"5,5 %","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"(169.559,00)","Gross Profit(4)":"104.956,00","   % Change YoY(5)":"6,7 %","   % Gross Margins(6)":"38,2 %","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"(19.916,00)","R&D Expenses(8)":"(18.752,00)","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"(38.668,00)","Operating Income(10)":"66.288,00","   % Change YoY(11)":"3,7 %","   % Operating Margins(12)":"24,1 %","Interest Expense(13)":"(2873,00)","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"3763,00","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"(87,00)","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"67.091,00","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"67.091,00","Income Tax Expense(19)":"(9680,00)","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"57.411,00","Net Income to Company(21)":"57.411,00","Net Income(22)":"57.411,00","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"57.411,00","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"20,9 %","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"57.411,00","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"20,9 %","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"3,28","   % Change YoY(28)":"10,4 %","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"17.528,21","   % Change YoY(30)":"(5,7 %)","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"17.352,12","   % Change YoY(32)":"(6,1 %)","Dividends Per Share(33)":"0,80","   % Change YoY(34)":"6,0 %","Payout Ratio %(35)":"24,5 %","Basic EPS(36)":"3,31","EBITDA(37)":"77.344,00","   % Change YoY(38)":"1,1 %","EBITDAR(39)":"88.144,00","R&D Expense(40)":"18.752,00","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":"14,4 %"},
        "25/9/21":
            {"Revenues(0)":"365.817,00","Total Revenues(1)":"365.817,00","   % Change YoY(2)":"33,3 %","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"(212.981,00)","Gross Profit(4)":"152.836,00","   % Change YoY(5)":"45,6 %","   % Gross Margins(6)":"41,8 %","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"(21.973,00)","R&D Expenses(8)":"(21.914,00)","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"(43.887,00)","Operating Income(10)":"108.949,00","   % Change YoY(11)":"64,4 %","   % Operating Margins(12)":"29,8 %","Interest Expense(13)":"(2645,00)","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"2843,00","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"60,00","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"109.207,00","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"109.207,00","Income Tax Expense(19)":"(14.527,00)","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"94.680,00","Net Income to Company(21)":"94.680,00","Net Income(22)":"94.680,00","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"94.680,00","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"25,9 %","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"94.680,00","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"25,9 %","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"5,61","   % Change YoY(28)":"71,0 %","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"16.864,92","   % Change YoY(30)":"(3,8 %)","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"16.701,27","   % Change YoY(32)":"(3,8 %)","Dividends Per Share(33)":"0,85","   % Change YoY(34)":"6,9 %","Payout Ratio %(35)":"15,3 %","Basic EPS(36)":"5,67","EBITDA(37)":"120.233,00","   % Change YoY(38)":"55,5 %","EBITDAR(39)":"134.833,00","R&D Expense(40)":"21.914,00","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":"13,3 %"},
        "LTM":
            {"Revenues(0)":"378.323,00","Total Revenues(1)":"378.323,00","   % Change YoY(2)":"","Cost of Goods Sold(3)":"(215.572,00)","Gross Profit(4)":"162.751,00","   % Change YoY(5)":"","   % Gross Margins(6)":"43,0 %","Selling General & Admin Expenses(7)":"(22.791,00)","R&D Expenses(8)":"(23.057,00)","Other Operating Expenses(9)":"(45.848,00)","Operating Income(10)":"116.903,00","   % Change YoY(11)":"","   % Operating Margins(12)":"30,9 %","Interest Expense(13)":"(2701,00)","Interest And Investment Income(14)":"2746,00","Currency Exchange Gains (Loss)(15)":"","Other Non Operating Income (Expenses)(16)":"(79,00)","EBT Excl. Unusual Items(17)":"116.869,00","EBT Incl. Unusual Items(18)":"116.869,00","Income Tax Expense(19)":"(16.314,00)","Earnings From Continuing Operations(20)":"100.555,00","Net Income to Company(21)":"100.555,00","Net Income(22)":"100.555,00","Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items(23)":"100.555,00","   % Net Income to Common Incl Extra Items Margins(24)":"26,6 %","Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items(25)":"100.555,00","   % Net Income to Common Excl. Extra Items Margins(26)":"26,6 %","Diluted EPS Excl Extra Items(27)":"6,02","   % Change YoY(28)":"","Weighted Average Diluted Shares Outstanding(29)":"16.716,32","   % Change YoY(30)":"","Weighted Average Basic Shares Outstanding(31)":"16.565,42","   % Change YoY(32)":"","Dividends Per Share(33)":"0,87","   % Change YoY(34)":"","Payout Ratio %(35)":"14,5 %","Basic EPS(36)":"6,07","EBITDA(37)":"128.218,00","   % Change YoY(38)":"","EBITDAR(39)":"","R&D Expense(40)":"23.057,00","Selling and Marketing Expense(41)":"","Effective Tax Rate %(42)":"14,0 %"}}}
```

I dont know how to do it. I ave spent hours trying but all in vain. Here is what I have tried till now

```
dic_income = {}

with open('test.csv','r') as inc:
    lines = inc.readlines()
    in_income = {}
    col = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(',') and line.strip().endswith(','):
            continue
        ln = line.strip().split(',')

        for i in ln:
            if lines.index(line) == 0:
                if i == '':
                    pass
                else:
                    col.append(i)
                dic_income_key = ln[0]
                
                if ln.index(i) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    in_income[i] = {}
            else:
                pass
                

    dic_income[dic_income_key] = in_income
    print(dic_income)
    df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=col)
    print(df[col[0]])
```

It gives only output for one line and now I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below will give you what you want:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
dictionary = {}
columns = df.columns
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for column in columns:
    if row["Income Statement"] != row["Income Statement"]:
      continue
    else:
      if column == "Income Statement":
        continue
      if "Income Statement" not in dictionary:
        dictionary["Income Statement"] = {}
      if column not in dictionary["Income Statement"]:
        dictionary["Income Statement"][column] = {}
      if row[column] != row[column]:
        toPut = ""
      else:
        toPut = row[column]
      dictionary["Income Statement"][column][row["Income Statement"]] = toPut
print(json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))
```

##### Output

```
{
    "Income Statement": {
        "24/09/16": {
            "Revenues": "",
            "Total Revenues": "",
            "% Change YoY": "",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "",
            "Gross Profit": "",
            "% Gross Margins": "",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "",
            "R&D Expenses": "",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "",
            "Operating Income": ""
        },
        "30/09/17": {
            "Revenues": "229234.00",
            "Total Revenues": "229234.00",
            "% Change YoY": "",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "(141,048.00)",
            "Gross Profit": "88186.00",
            "% Gross Margins": "38.5%",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "(15,261.00)",
            "R&D Expenses": "(11,581.00)",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "(26,842.00)",
            "Operating Income": "61344.00"
        },
        "29/09/18": {
            "Revenues": "265595.00",
            "Total Revenues": "265595.00",
            "% Change YoY": "15.6%",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "(163,756.00)",
            "Gross Profit": "101839.00",
            "% Gross Margins": "38.3%",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "(16,705.00)",
            "R&D Expenses": "(14,236.00)",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "(30,941.00)",
            "Operating Income": "70898.00"
        },
        "28/09/19": {
            "Revenues": "260174.00",
            "Total Revenues": "260174.00",
            "% Change YoY": "(9.8%)",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "(161,782.00)",
            "Gross Profit": "98392.00",
            "% Gross Margins": "37.8%",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "(18,245.00)",
            "R&D Expenses": "(16,217.00)",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "(34,462.00)",
            "Operating Income": "63930.00"
        },
        "26/09/20": {
            "Revenues": "274515.00",
            "Total Revenues": "274515.00",
            "% Change YoY": "3.7%",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "(169,559.00)",
            "Gross Profit": "104956.00",
            "% Gross Margins": "38.2%",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "(19,916.00)",
            "R&D Expenses": "(18,752.00)",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "(38,668.00)",
            "Operating Income": "66288.00"
        },
        "25/09/21": {
            "Revenues": "365817.00",
            "Total Revenues": "365817.00",
            "% Change YoY": "64.4%",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "(212,981.00)",
            "Gross Profit": "152836.00",
            "% Gross Margins": "41.8%",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "(21,973.00)",
            "R&D Expenses": "(21,914.00)",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "(43,887.00)",
            "Operating Income": "108949.00"
        },
        "LTM": {
            "Revenues": "378323.00",
            "Total Revenues": "378323.00",
            "% Change YoY": "",
            "Cost of Goods Sold": "(215,572.00)",
            "Gross Profit": "162751.00",
            "% Gross Margins": "43.0%",
            "Selling General & Admin Expenses": "(22,791.00)",
            "R&D Expenses": "(23,057.00)",
            "Other Operating Expenses": "(45,848.00)",
            "Operating Income": "116903.00"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does if ‘row[Income Statement] != row[Income Statement]’ mean?

Comment: @ZachYoung Interesting question, Zach. In the `iterrows` loop, I wanted to check if the value of the `Income Statement` column is `nan`. But how would you check if the value of a cell is equal to `nan`? By comparing it with `nan` itself, or `"nan"` as a string or `None`? None of them is working. You just need to check it with itself because `nan` values are not equal to themselves. For more information, please check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704124/using-not-equal-and-nan-together-in-python